# How to sort a list of users through cloud firestore that contain a uid with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a leaderboard system for a game that I am coming up within flutter and I can't seem to find a way to sort the different users depending on their high score due to the fact that high score data is stored inside the document which is the uid?

Right now I have it set up to just display the different users in the order at which they sign in at. Thanks for all the help in advance!

```
// My home page
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  final HighscoreData highscoreData;

  Home({Key key, this.highscoreData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return StreamProvider<List<HighscoreData>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().brews,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
        body: HighscoreList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}





// List of different players highscores
class HighscoreList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HighscoreListState createState() => _HighscoreListState();
}

class _HighscoreListState extends State<HighscoreList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final differentHighScores = Provider.of<List<HighscoreData>>(context) ?? [];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: differentHighScores.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
        return PlayerHighscoreTile(highscoreData: differentHighScores[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}




// The template tile for each different highscore
class PlayerHighscoreTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final HighscoreData highscoreData;

  PlayerHighscoreTile({ this.highscoreData });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0.0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 25.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
          ),
          title: Text(highscoreData.name),
          trailing: Text(highscoreData.score),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my Database class if it helps at all

```
class DatabaseService {

  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({ this.uid });

  // Collection reference
  final CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> brewCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('brews');



  Future updateUserData( String name, score) async {
    return await brewCollection.doc(uid).set({
      'score' : score,
      'name'  : name,
    });
  }


  // Brew list from snapshot
  List<HighscoreData> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return HighscoreData(
          name: doc.get('name') ?? '',
          score: doc.get('score') ?? '0'
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  // Get brews stream
  Stream<List<HighscoreData>> get brews {
    return brewCollection.snapshots().map(_brewListFromSnapshot);
  }

  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
        uid: uid,
        name: snapshot.get('name'),
        score: snapshot.get('score'),
    );
  }

  // Get user document
  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return brewCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }

}
```

Comment: you need to show us your Firestore queries if you want us to tell you what's wrong, these widgets tell us nothing and are irrelevant to your question

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Thanks, @AlexMamo! you are totally right. I was thinking of adding a 'orderBy' function but am not entirely sure of where I would even do it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still can't get your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how to do this by adding a sortBy() function as it grabs the different data from firebase.

```
  Stream<List<HighscoreData>> get brews {
    return brewCollection.orderBy('').snapshots().map(_brewListFromSnapshot);
  }
```